# gRPC authentication with metadata

Tags: node.js, grpc

I'm wondering how I can get authentication setup on my gRPC service? I've read that metadata is the way to go.

Using the Node.js grpc library and grpcc to test my implementation. I basically have a JWT token being received on every request, just no way to digest and validate it over the gRPC pipe.

Suggestions/guidance is most appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Node gRPC does not currently expose functionality to process authentication tokens on the server. The token should show up with the rest of the metadata on the server, but you will have to process it on your own.

Comment: Yeah after I posted the question I learned that the request object comes with the Metadata class so that I can retrieve the token value. Thanks